# LINQ Left Join with group by and count

Tags: c#, linq

I am having fun with LINQ query and kind of stuck at figuring out the correct method to get Count of associated entries.

I have below LINQ query and

```
var result = (from OR in orders
                join OE in order_entries on OR.id equals OE.order_id into temp
                from LOE in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                group LOE  by new {OR.user_id, OR.site } into g
                select new {
                   col1 = g.Key.user_id,
                   col2 = g.Key.site,
                   count = g.Count() ,
                   cost = g.Sum( oe => oe.cost)
                }
);
```

this turns to

```
SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [user_id], 
    [GroupBy1].[K2] AS [site], 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C2], 
    [GroupBy1].[A2] AS [C3]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[user_id] AS [K1], 
        [Extent1].[site] AS [K2], 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1], 
        SUM([Extent2].[cost]) AS [A2]
        FROM  [dbo].[orders] AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[order_entries] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[id] = [Extent2].[order_id]
        GROUP BY [Extent1].[user_id], [Extent1].[site]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

What I am trying to acheive here is replace Count(1) with Count([Extent2].[id]) so in case when there is no entries associated with the order I want to show 0 instead of 1.

Can someone please help me with updating the LINQ query to achieve this ?

**UPDATE :**

replace with below will return the outcome for what I wanted but this also turns my sql query to perform slower..

```
g.Where(i => i.orders != null).Count(),
```

Comment: You could try `count = g.Select(x => x.id).Count()` or even add `Distinct` if it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work since I have id column both in orders and order_entries table. When I added that, it didn't change any query I think it thinks id is from orders table.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use [subqueries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311041.aspx):

```
    var qry = from o in orders
        select new {
            oid = o.ID,
            uid = o.UserId,
            site = o.Site,
            count = order_entries.Where(oe=>oe.OrderId == o.ID).Count(),
            cost = order_entries.Where(oe=>oe.OrderId == o.ID).Sum(oe=>oe.Cost)
            };
```

But if you would like to join two data sets, use this:

```
    var qry = (from o in orders join oe in order_entries on o.ID equals oe.OrderId into grp 
        from g in grp.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new{
            oid = o.ID,
            uid = o.UserId,
            site = o.Site,
            count = grp.Count(),
            cost = grp.Sum(e=>e.Cost)
            }).Distinct();
```

I strongly believe in it that second query could be writen in simplest way by using **group** statement.

Here is a complete [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) sample:

```
void Main()
{

    List<TOrder> orders = new List<TOrder>{
        new TOrder(1, 1, "Site1"),
        new TOrder(2, 1, "Site1"),
        new TOrder(3, 2, "Site2"),
        new TOrder(4, 2, "Site2"),
        new TOrder(5, 3, "Site3")
        };

    List<TOrderEntry> order_entries = new List<TOrderEntry>{
        new TOrderEntry(1, 1, 5.5),
        new TOrderEntry(2, 1, 6.2),
        new TOrderEntry(3, 1, 4.9),
        new TOrderEntry(4, 1, 55.15),
        new TOrderEntry(5, 1, 0.97),
        new TOrderEntry(6, 2, 2.23),
        new TOrderEntry(7, 2, 95.44),
        new TOrderEntry(8, 2, 3.88),
        new TOrderEntry(9, 2, 7.77),
        new TOrderEntry(10, 3, 25.23),
        new TOrderEntry(11, 3, 31.13),
        new TOrderEntry(12, 4, 41.14)
        };

//      var qry = from o in orders
//          select new {
//              oid = o.ID,
//              uid = o.UserId,
//              site = o.Site,
//              count = order_entries.Where(oe=>oe.OrderId == o.ID).Count(),
//              cost = order_entries.Where(oe=>oe.OrderId == o.ID).Sum(oe=>oe.Cost)
//              };
//      qry.Dump();

        var qry = (from o in orders join oe in order_entries on o.ID equals oe.OrderId into grp 
            from g in grp.DefaultIfEmpty()
            //group g by g into ggg
            select new{
                oid = o.ID,
                uid = o.UserId,
                site = o.Site,
                count = grp.Count(),
                cost = grp.Sum(e=>e.Cost)
                }).Distinct();
        qry.Dump();
}


// Define other methods and classes here
class TOrder
{
    private int iid =0;
    private int uid =0;
    private string ssite=string.Empty;

    public TOrder(int _id, int _uid, string _site)
    {
        iid = _id;  
        uid = _uid;
        ssite = _site;
    }

    public int ID
    {
        get{return iid;}
        set{iid = value;}
    }

    public int UserId
    {
        get{return uid;}
        set{uid = value;}
    }

    public string Site
    {
        get{return ssite;}
        set{ssite = value;}
    }
}


class TOrderEntry
{
    private int iid = 0;
    private int oid = 0;
    private double dcost = .0;

    public TOrderEntry(int _iid, int _oid, double _cost)
    {
        iid = _iid;
        oid = _oid;
        dcost = _cost;
    }

    public int EntryId
    {
        get{return iid;}
        set{iid = value;}
    }

    public int OrderId
    {
        get{return oid;}
        set{oid = value;}
    }

    public double Cost
    {
        get{return dcost;}
        set{dcost = value;}
    }

}
```